# WCF add object as a custom header

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to add the following class as a custom header. My client code:

```
var obj = new Class1 { PropA = "A", PropB = "B" };
var header = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("Class1", "Class1", obj);

var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(urlString), header);

ChannelFactory<TChannel>.CreateChannel(binding, address);


[DataContract]
public class Class1
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PropA { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}
```

I can see my header via Fiddler. But when I process request on service side, I can get Message Header, but properties (PropA, PropB) in the header are equal to null.

My server side code:

```
var obj = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<Class1>("Class1", "Class1");
```

Have can deserialize my custom header correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your code looks fine so I've created sample application and it works as you want. Please check it out, maybe you have missed something in your real code...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string urlString = "http://localhost:8081/test";

        using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(urlString)))
        {
            host.AddDefaultEndpoints();
            host.Open();

            var obj = new Class1 { PropA = "A", PropB = "B" };
            var header = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("Class1", "Class1", obj);

            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(urlString), header);

            var channel =  ChannelFactory<IService>.CreateChannel(binding, address);
            channel.DoWork();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
class Class1
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PropA { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();
}

class Service : IService
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        var obj = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<Class1>("Class1", "Class1");
        Console.WriteLine("PropA: " + obj.PropA);
        Console.WriteLine("PropB: " + obj.PropB);
    }
}
```

output:

[image: result]

Comment: I am using console application for hosting. Maybe, this couse the problem. I will send my all properties with different headers. Thanks.